# Can't create RFCOMM TTY: Address already in use

Tags: 14.04, bluetooth

The following error occurs when I issue `sudo rfcomm listen rfcomm0`

> Can't create RFCOMM TTY: Address already in use

I received some serial Bluetooth data in a Python program beforehand. So, it seems something gets stuck.

Then I type `sudo rfcomm release rfcomm0` which yields:

> Can't release device: Operation already in progress

How can I make a hard release? For now the only way to get it working again is to reboot.

Comment: Same problem here.

Comment: SOLUTION I was having a very similar issue, check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46735997/cant-create-rfcomm-tty-address-already-in-use/46915801#

Answer (score 1):

Ok since rebooting is annoying, I have tried two approaches.

- Create another device and bind the bluetooth to it. Then use the new one in your program.

Open /etc/bluetooth/rfcomm.conf and add another device.

> rfcomm0 {   # Automatically bind the device at startup   bind no;   #
>   Bluetooth address of the device   device 00:06:66:68:20:61;   # RFCOMM
>   channel for the connection   channel 1;   # Description of the
>   connection   comment "This is Device 1's serial port."; }
>
> rfcomm2 {   # Automatically bind the device at startup   bind no;   #
>   Bluetooth address of the device   device 20:15:12:08:62:95;   # RFCOMM
>   channel for the connection   channel 1;   # Description of the
>   connection   comment "This is Device 1's serial port."; }
>
> rfcomm3 {   # Automatically bind the device at startup   bind no;   #
>   Bluetooth address of the device   device 20:15:12:08:62:95;   # RFCOMM
>   channel for the connection   channel 1;   # Description of the
>   connection   comment "This is Device 1's serial port."; }

Restart the bluetooth service then :

```
userk@dopamine:~$ sudo rfcomm bind 2 DEV_ADDR CHANNEL
```

- **The answer**:

Rfcomm can't release the device because of some other process in Ubuntu. Check which one with

```
userk@dopamine:~$ sudo lsof | grep /dev/rfcomm2

MATLAB    5554 6868            userk  514u      CHR              216,2       0t0        603 /dev/rfcomm2
```

Kill it!!

```
userk@dopamine:~$ ps -ax | grep MATLAB
 7684 pts/5    Sl     0:39 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/bin/glnxa64/MATLAB
 7873 pts/5    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto MATLAB

userk@dopamine:~$ kill -9 7684
```

Voilà no ore forced reboot! Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Quite late here but I had this same issue on Ubuntu 16.04.

What I did was the following:

```
sudo service bluetooth restart
```

Which gave me the error:

```
Warning: bluetooth.service changed on disk. Run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to reload units.
```

After running the suggested command in the warning I was able to succesfully restart the bluetooth service and commence listening on the port.

I suspect that in my case I changed a config (running `bluetoothd` with the --compat argument) and therefor the init system had to reload.